# Should I use serialize to store availability times?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a site that requires users to enter days and times they would be available to teach. For example, a professor could enter Mondays 1:00 PM to 2:00 PM and Tuesdays 2:00 PM to 4:00 PM.

Currently I am storing the data in a MySQL table in a column called "availability" using serialize. I take Monday+1300+1400 and Tuesday+1400+1500 and serialize those two. I then use explode() to extract Monday, 1300, 1400 etc.

I feel that there should be a better way to do this. I will need to extract this information each time a student wants to see teacher availability, and I think this current method is not efficient for this.

Can you please let me know a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current solution will not allow you to search based on availability on the DB itself. You'd be required to fetch the serialized data, deserialize and then inspect it, which would be extremely expensive.

What you should do is set up a table that looks somewhat like this:

`User_id  |  Day  |  Start_Time | End_Time`

Now, if a user with user_id is free on Mon from 2-3pm and Fri from 4-5pm, add two entries to this table

```
1  |  Mon  |  1400  |  1500
1  |  Fri  |  1600  |  1700
```

You can now easily search, filter, sort etc. on the DB itself.

Comment: Isn't security a top priority regardless?

Comment: How does serializing provide any form of security?

Comment: A relation table is definitely the best for DB structure here. However, you can also write the teacher's schedule to flat text on change and only perform the lookup during specific searches if the goal is to minimize queries.

Comment: I had one question though. Let's say a user has multiple time slots in one day like Monday 2-3PM and 4-5PM. How would it work if a user wants to delete or change their 2-3PM time slot? How would I identify that row?

Comment: Add another column to your table called `Slot_ID` or something and set it as PK and auto-increment. That way, you can then uniquely identify each row in the table.